# Use python to generate graph using node constraints

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, networkx

Im trying to solve a problem i have with my system (Python/Storm), but not sure what's the best tool.

**The Goal: create the edges of a graph, using constraints on the Node input and output.**

i have around 400+ python function(apache storm shell bolts each bolt wrap one function - Storm doesn't really matter in this case, i will treat them as nodes ).

Each bolt/function/Node has a defined input and output name-attributes list. 
i have a source (which has output, but NO input).
Nodes (have input and output list)
Sink (only input no output).

To Make it more clear lets say i have:

```
S = Source , Input = [] , Output = ["a","b","c","d"] ("a","b","c","d" are attributes the sources produces).
A = Node , Input = ["a","b"], output = ["e"]
B = Node , Input = ["a","e"], output = ["f"]
Si = Sink, Input = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"] , Output = []
```

I would like NetworkX (or other graph library) to create the edges alone using those constraints on the Node.

Each node output is ONLY the output list, not output+input.

the output i want is the list of edges:

```
S,A
S,B
A,B
B,Si
A,Si
S,Si
```

[image]

*in the graph C=Si

Does NetworkX support such a build? and if so how can i implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a bipartite graph (I think directed?) from your data and than "project" it onto one set of nodes to make the graph you want.  E.g. if you have the directed edges S->a and a->T the two node sets are {S,T} and {a}.  Projecting onto the node set {S,T} gives S->T because there is a path from S->T in the original bipartite graph.

```
import networkx as nx

data = [("S", [], ["a","b","c","d"]),
        ("A", ["a","b"], ["e"]),
        ("B", ["a","c"], ["f"]),
        ("Si", ["a","b","c","d","e","f"], [])]

G = nx.DiGraph()
#G = nx.Graph() # maybe you want an undirected graph?
nodes = []
for n,inedges,outedges in data:
    nodes.append(n)
    for s in inedges:
        G.add_edge(s,n)
    for t in outedges:
        G.add_edge(n,t)

P = nx.projected_graph(G,nodes)

print list(P.nodes())
print list(P.edges())
# OUTPUT
# ['A', 'S', 'B', 'Si']
# [('A', 'Si'), ('S', 'A'), ('S', 'Si'), ('S', 'B'), ('B', 'Si')]
```

Comment: Just what i wanted!
 i also fixed my example to a more complicated one (the one i originally meant) .
tried your code and it worked great on it.